# Fan noise and battery consumption

Tags: drivers, battery, amd-graphics, fan, amdgpu

I observe some problems with my ubuntu laptop 18.04.

When I'm using my laptop the fan can become very noisy for a long time period. I notice that can occur after watching videos but not only.

Moreover, I find that the battery consumption is relatively high (~ 2 hours).

- I installed tlp and powertop but there does not seem to have any effect
- Is there a problem with hybrid graphics in my case
- Do I need to install another graphics card driver

Are these problems related ?

Thanks in advance

**`lspci -v | grep VGA` output**

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
03:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e6
```

**`lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3` output**

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1831]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
--
03:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e6]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15e4]
    Kernel driver in use: i2c_amd_mp2
    Kernel modules: i2c_amd_mp2_pci
```

Comment: You need to make sure the cooling system is clean and free of dust, and also monitor the temretures of the CPU and GPU. As the laptop seems to be quite new, you might benefit from an upgrade to 20.04, which should provide better hardware support.

Answer (score 0):

Like mikewhatever said, sounds like your problem is more hardware than software.
Every once in an while you are supposed to clean your computers using compressed air, to ensure there is no dust collected in the fan(s)
dust is electronics archenemy. dust sticks to the worst part of the motherboards and absorb any moisture in the air(you know water and electricity don't mix)
good luck!